# Converting numeric type vector into a vector of strings

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert this:

```
> j[1:5] 
NA06985 NA06991 NA06993 NA06994 NA07000
```

Into this:

```
c("NA06985","NA06991","NA06993", "NA06994", "NA07000")
```

I've tried using as.character but it gives me:

```
> as.character(j[1:5])
[1] "10" "10" "10" "10" "10"
```

Help please!
-Josh

EDIT:
Okay so I think I figured it out. After doing class(j) I found that it was of type data.frame. So I converted to as.matrix and it worked..hooray!

Comment: The answer to this will probably be fairly simple if you share the output of `str(j)`.

Comment: Can you post *exactly* what you see when you type j[1:5] ? And what is class(j)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I think I figured it out. After doing class(j) I found that it was of type data.frame. So I converted to as.matrix and it worked..hooray!

Answer (score 11):

`paste(j[1:5])`

This works for strings, factors, numerics, pretty much anything that can be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Assumming that j is a factor

```
> j <- factor(c("NA06985","NA06991","NA06993", "NA06994", "NA07000", "extra level"))
> j
[1] NA06985     NA06991     NA06993     NA06994     NA07000     extra level
Levels: extra level NA06985 NA06991 NA06993 NA06994 NA07000
> levels(j)[j[1:5]]
[1] "NA06985" "NA06991" "NA06993" "NA06994" "NA07000"
```

Comment: This is fine, but as.character(j[1:5]) would work as well for this case. It seems there is something different about j in the OP's question, or they are simply not reporting the issue accurately.